# MYSQL - How to let 3 row data become 1 row data

Tags: mysql, sql

Now I union 3 table and select become below show.

```
|remark|totalA|totalB|tatalC|
-----------------------------
|   a  | 123  | NULL | NULL |

|   a  | NULL | 123  | NULL |

|   a  | NULL | NULL | 123  |
```

How to let it become 1 row as below show?

```
|remark|totalA|totalB|tatalC|
-----------------------------
|   a  | 123  | 123  | 123  |
```

I trying group and distinct it but it show below

```
|remark|totalA|totalB|tatalC|
-----------------------------
|   a  | 123  | NULL | NULL |
```

Comment: Though this can be solved easily by grouping and using an aggregate function such as min, max or sum, it might be better to use joins or subqueries instead of unions in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
   remark,
   sum(totalA) as totalA,
   sum(totalB) as totalB,
   sum(totalC) as totalC
from the_table
group by remark
```

Answer (score 2):

Use`sum` along with `group by` as

```
select remark, sum(totalA), sum(totalB), sum(totalC)
from table_name
group by remark
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an aggregate function, like `MIN()`, which will exclude nulls by default:

```
SELECT remark, MIN(totalA), MIN(totalB), MIN(totalC)
FROM Remarks
GROUP BY remark
```